# How to know if it's actually a 404 page?

Tags: http, webserver, http-status-code-404

What I learned from [Foregenix](http://faq.foregenix.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=16&id=15&artlang=en):

> The HTTP 404 Not Found Error means that the webpage you were trying to reach could not be found on the server. It is a Client-side Error which means that either the page has been removed or moved and the URL was not changed accordingly, or that you typed in the URL incorrectly

But then I also do web app pentests with Python and I am wondering that if I only check for the String `404` on the page, it may not really be a `404` error.
It can so happen that the page exists but the heading is `404` just to fool us.

So how exactly do I find out?

Comment: HTTP status codes, such as 404, can be obtained in a much more reliable way by looking at the HTTP response. For example, see http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPResponseMessageFormat.htm

Comment: @A.Darwin I would rewrite your comment a bit and post that as an answer

Comment: When quoting some webpage, please include a direct link to where you got the quote from. Thank you!

Comment: So when you ask a server for a webpage, you get a page that says "404". Whether or not it's a 'real' 404, what would you say it means for a page to 'exist' and yet not be served when requested?

Comment: @AakashM it could mean that you cannot have authorization to access the page (which normally would yield a 403-Forbidden), but the admin doesn't want you to know that page even exists. In fact, some tools enumerate "interesting" pages by looking for a 403 status code. Writing a different code makes the page less appealing to someone who is trying to enumerate your website.directories and files.

Comment: Wait guys, I'll come online at night , that time I'll read all answers and accept one now I have to go to school I am being late

Comment: Since when is a 404 error a "client-side" error? I also fail to see what at all the linked page has to do with Google. Please clarify.

Comment: By that metric I can say that virtually *any* web page is Google. Just because you found it by doing a Google search doesn't mean it is Google. Also, casting such a wide net is virtually guaranteed to result in different sets of hits for different people depending on Google's proprietary algorithms and what data they have available on your particular browsing habits.

Comment: I know that dude ; Google took info from some other site

Comment: Sorry for pointing out the obvious, but this very page, the one you are looking at right now, contains '404' in its title and many more in the text.  And vice versa, a 404 page doesn't have to contain the magic number in its title or text. Status code is the thing to check, as others have already mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, the request for the entity could not be fulfilled, hence an HTTP-level "error". This was because the client requested a resource that does not exist. Of course, the chain of causation might not be the client's "fault", but that's the most that can be said programatically.

Comment: 404 means not available, not "not found". a subtle but important difference when it comes to leaking application outlines.

Comment: @dandavis what do you mean? The official name for 404 is "not found", and in my opinion "not available" sounds more like the description of 410-Gone,401, or 403 than that of 404.

Comment: @A.Darwin:  about 5 years ago, folks were advising site admins to use language like "_The requested resource is not available_" so that anon useragents can't tell if a section is one _they_ aren't supposed to see or something that's not there at all. never-mind i guess.

Comment: Keep in mind some web applications might know the resource is not found and redirect you to a custom 404 page without forcing the 404 status code in the response headers. As a result the 404 will return 200 OK instead. This is particularly a bad habit I have seen increasing in use despite the back end language allowing them to set a status code in the header.

Comment: @baconface Indeed; [it wreaks havoc with archiving, too](http://blog.dshr.org/2015/02/the-evanescent-web.html "David Rosenthal / DSHR: The Evanescent Web (Tuesday, February 10, 2015)").

Comment: @PaulDraper: It's not an error, it is a status. You ask for a resource, and status 404 tells you that it isn't there. It's not an error. The server is able to respond correctly to your request, and it does respond correctly to your request. Asking for a page that doesn't exist is not an error. That's why it is called "http status".

Comment: @gnasher729, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4

Comment: The quoted text is wrong and bloody stupid, too. `HTTP 404 Not Found` is a message from the server, *not* a client-side error.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you. I wish I could accept all answers but this website allows only one. Just thank you so much. I did a broad thinking finally

Comment: @reinierpost, it's a *message from the server* about *a client-side error*. Or to quote the HTTP spec (which knows quite a bit about HTTP) "cases in which the client seems to have erred". The resource could not be delivered (or operated on, depending on the method) because the client asked for a non-existent one.

Comment: @Paul Draper: I see.  What a strange way of putting it. "The customer is always wrong."

Comment: God knows why my question is migrated to stackoverflow ..

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can check the HTTP status code, and see if it is 404 or not. The status code is on the first line of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

If you are using [HTTPlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) you can just read the `status` property of the `HTTPResponse` object.

However, it is the server that decides what HTTP status code to send. Just because 404 is defined to mean "page not found" does not mean the server can not lie to you. It is quite common to do things like this:

- Send 404 instead of 403, to hide the resource that requires authentication.
- Send 404 instead of 500, to hide the fact something is not working.
- Send 404 when your IP is blocked for some reason.

Without access to the server, it is impossible to know what is really going on behind the curtains.

Comment: Some sites mangle the status code quite a bit. They may display a 404 but return a 200 (as you stated). If you find a site doing that you should contact them and let them know, specially if your using an API end point.

Comment: sometimes apps use a non-404 status so that ajax calls still route through a `success` handler, usually when they don't code a `catch/onerror` handler.

Comment: @coteyr And I've encountered multiple sites that take a 404 and either simply return the home page or take the URL segments as a search on their site and return a search result page.  (Actually a sensible course of action if they use descriptive URLs--such a search will sometimes find the new home of a missing page.)

Comment: ... and send 404 instead of 418 [when you're a teapot](https://httpstatuses.com/418).

Comment: @coteyr I do think this is what Google calls a "[Soft 404 error](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en)".

Comment: @UweKeim Google "Soft 404 error" is 302 temporary redirect.

Answer (score 9):

You are right: someone could write "404 Page Not Found" in a HTML page and make you think that the page doesn't exist.

In order to properly recognize HTTP status codes such as the 404, you should capture the HTTP response with Python and parse it. HTTP 1 and HTTP 2 standards dictate that an HTTP response, which is written in the HTTP generic message format, must contain the status code.

Example of an HTTP response (from [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_responses.htm)):

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 18 Oct 2012 10:36:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)
Content-Length: 230
Connection: Closed
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Not Found</h1>
   <p>The requested URL /t.html was not found on this server.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You should definitely not trust the HTML part, which can show a 404 error (or even a [418 I'm a teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol)) when the page can in fact be found.

Comment: I agree you should not trust the HTML, but should you trust the HTTP status code?

Comment: @Anders If the page sends you an HTTP response containing a fake status code, I don't know what else could be done in order to check if the page cannot be found, short of checking it with another IP address or user-agent if it is an ad-hoc message.

Comment: @Anders: You should trust the status code. If the site is broken or intentionally playing games with you, there is nothing you can do. If the site says "the page isn't there", then as far as you are concerned, it isn't there.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Anders' answer, I found a way to detect some cases where 404 is misused with a Timing attack. It is hardly reliable, though.

- Send 404 instead of 403, to hide the resource that requires authentication.

Often servers need more time to determine that "you dont have authorization to get this resource", because they need more roundtrips to external resources like databases, then they need to determine "this is not there", quite often even cacheable and quickly to determine.

A typical example in an MVC application with a RDBS as backend is the difference between a simple`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articles WHERE id=123 LIMIT 1`
and the much more complex `SELECT access FROM accesses JOIN articles ON articles.id = accesses.foreign_id WHERE articles.id = 123 AND accesses.type='articles' AND accesses.user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE token='t0k3n' LIMIT 1)`. And that implies that the application can make such single line queries in the first place: more often it is a lot of "fetch a user, extract some data, now fetch a Thing, now ask Thing if user may access it through an authorization-api".

Unless the developers or the framework of the site took care to cover this case, quite often you'll see a notable difference in time to serve both cases of 404.

- Send 404 instead of 500, to hide the fact something is not working.

Typically, crashing or unexpected errors occur only after some code has ran. 404-detection often comes early: after all, it is cheap to determine that something is not there (see above). Whereas the error would occur later on. Meaning that such a 500-hidden-as-404-error would, quite often take a lot longer to reach you then a normal 404.

- Send 404 when your IP is blocked for some reason.

Here, the timing is often the other way around, depending on the implementation. Such IP-blocking would often be kept outside of the web-app (CMS etc) because it is much simpler and performant to handle higher up in the stack: the webserver, a proxy etc.
However, when the application itself takes care of this, generating an actual 404 is often reasonably cheap, whereas looking an IP in a database, applying masks and so on, takes some time. Similar to hiding a 403 as 404.